# Stop IIS without confirmation box - Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation

I'm trying to stop an iis site using PS, but also trying to skip the annoying confirmation box

If I run the following script accepting the confirmation it will stop it just fine

```
SAPS PowerShell  -Verb RunAs  -ArgumentList "Stop-IISSite -Name 'website'"
```

However if I add the cmdlet to set the confirmation as false it does not give me any error or the confirmation, but it doesn't stop the site.

```
SAPS PowerShell  -Verb RunAs  -ArgumentList "Stop-IISSite -Name 'website' -Force -Confirm:$false"
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

The `$false` is being expanded when you pass the string to `ArgumentList`. Either use single quotes or escape the `$` used in `$false` so it doesn't get expanded until the child process executes:

```
# Use double-quotes and escape the $ if you have a variable that *does*
# need to be expanded in the current session executes,
# such as the -Name
"Stop-IISSite -Name $name -Force -Confirm:`$false"

# Otherwise single-quotes will prevent any variable expansion from
# the current session
'Stop-IISSite -Name ''website'' -Force -Confirm:$false'
```

The way you are doing it now causes the command to be rendered in the child PowerShell process as follows:

```
Stop-IISSite -Name $name -Force -Confirm:false
```

Note the missing `$` after `-Confirm:`, but forcibly setting a `[switch]` state requires a `[bool]` type. `$false` is a `[bool]`, but when rendered in a string like this it will be evaluated to the literal string `false`.

I'm surprised you aren't getting an error though, since `-Confirm:false` throws a type conversion error. This could be explained if you have `$ErrorActionPreference` set to `SilentlyContinue` or `Ignore` elsewhere, but is more likely that the error is showing in the child process window quickly before the window closes.

---

[This article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-here-strings/) explains variable expansion in strings in more detail if you want to know more.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Stop-Website -Name 'website', this will not ask for confirmation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31241615)